# How to send the url's parameter to filter.php and retrieve it there?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

How to send the url's parameter to filter.php and retrieve it there?

Route

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');
```

I want to send the {id} from the above URL to the filter.php and retrieve it's value there

something like this

```
Route::filter('access', function($id)
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            if (Auth::user()->is_admin != 1 && Auth::user()->id = $id) {
                return View::make('users.noaccess');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('/')->with('error', 'Please login to access this page');
        }
    });
```

and then used beforeFilter to bind the filter to the method

```
$this->beforeFilter('access', array('only' => 'edit'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter closure function accepts a number of parameters (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters). You can rewrite your filter like this:

```
Route::filter('access', function($route) {
   $id = $route->parameter('id');
   if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->is_admin != 1 && Auth::user()->id = $id) {
            return View::make('users.noaccess');
        }
   } else {
        return Redirect::guest('/')->with('error', 'Please login to access this page');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks cdarken! In my first try it didn't work but I just noticed that the problem was with my question. The exact route was not `Route::get('/users/{id}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');` but `Route::get('/users/{users}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');` so changed the `$id = $route->parameter('id');` to `$id = $route->parameter('users');`